Cocoa App trying to display document icon despite not being document based
I'm working on a Cocoa/AppKit Mac app, and after customizing the File menu items (save and new), I now get a blank document icon on my app. My app is not document based however, so it simply displays some invalid location <NSWindow/0x60000...>
How can I get Xcode to stop adding this icon to my app's title bar?
I've tried looking through the changes in Main.storyboard, however I can't find anything that specifically relates to somehow converting my app into being document-based.
Blank document icon
Here is the titlebar of my app which shows a blank document icon
Invalid location of the "document"
And this is what happens when I right-click on it. It is pointing to the location where the app is launched.

Post a [mre] please.

Blank document icon is as expected. Any screenshot of what is wrong. Is not clear what you are asking. Check your info.plist for CFBundleDocumentTypes and your Assets..xcassets for AppIcon etc.

@Willeke unfortunately I can't seem to reproduce it in a new Xcode project.

@MarekH I added screenshots. I've checked in Info.plist, I don't have any document types, nor do I have any icons in my project whatsoever.

I took another look at the Main.storyboard file, and this was the culprit:
<connections>
    <binding destination="B8D-0N-5wS" name="representedFilename" keyPath="self.window" id="yWp-EG-r02"/>
    <outlet property="delegate" destination="B8D-0N-5wS" id="MS0-qL-3Yx"/>
</connections>

I don't know how it got in there, but removing it did the trick.
